# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^{2}-1}=\frac{\pi -2}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to prove the equation below:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^{2}-1}=\frac{\pi -2}{4}$$

I think that I can use the following result provided by Fourier Series:

$$|\sin\theta|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2n\theta)}{4n^{2}-1} $$

Can I take some value of $\theta$ that will give me the formula? Because $$\cos(2n\theta)=(-1)^{n+1}\Rightarrow 2n\theta=(n+1)\pi\Rightarrow \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)$$
does not help me. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try with $\theta=\pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking advantage of periodicity. E.g. your implication should be $2n\theta+2k\pi = (n+1)\pi$, for any integer $k$. Setting $k=n$, gives you $\theta=\pi/2$, so that $\cos(2n\theta)=\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$. Can you finish he problem from here?

Comment: I guess not, because I need $\cos(2n\theta)=(-1)^{n+1}$. I tried to derive that from your answer, but I couldn't.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)(-1)^n$?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following, which is a result of Cosine Fourier Series, which is way easier (for your application) than using the Fourier series. The following is valid for $x \in [0,1]$:

\begin{equation}
\sin   \pi x\simeq
 \frac{2}{\pi}
 -
 \frac{4}{\pi}
 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}
 \cos( 2 \pi k x)
\end{equation}
Use $x = \frac{1}{2}$, we get
\begin{equation}
1
\simeq
 \frac{2}{\pi}
 -
 \frac{4}{\pi}
 \overbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}
 (-1)^k}^{\alpha}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 \pi = 2 - 4\alpha
\end{equation}
so we get $\alpha =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}
 (-1)^k= -\frac{\pi - 2}{4}$. Your summation is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}
 (-1)^{k+1} = -\alpha.$

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to specify the domain over which the Fourier series is equivalent to $\sin(\pi x)$ so that you can justify taking $x = 1/2$.

Comment: thanks @Mattos .. you're right.